# Why can React display an object but not its members?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongodb, express

I'm trying to wrap my head around the MERN stack. So far I've managed to query my database and get the data on an API endopoint, but I'm having some trouble getting it to show up on my front-end.

Here's my fronted code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component<{}, {res:any}> {
  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {res: Array};
}
  callAPI() {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({res: json}));
  }
  componentWillMount() {
      this.callAPI();
  }
  render() {
  // WORKS
  console.log(this.state.res[0]);
  // DOESN'T WORK
  console.log(this.state.res[0].name);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
    </div>
  )};
}

export default App;
```

As you can see it's just a modified version of the default React homepage. I just added a state and fetching data from  my backend.

The problem comes when I try to console.log my data.

If I `console.log(this.state.res[0])`, everything is fine, and I get `{ "_id": "62207b47d40bca8ea8b60560", "name": "Patère", "checked": false, "links": [ "" ] }` in my console. But if I try to only log the name, I get `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.res[0] is undefined`, which is weird, since it managed to display `this.state.res[0]` just fine before ?

What's causing this and how can I fix it ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't you have more than 2 logs in the console ? Because the component should be rendered once before the API answer, and a 2nd time after the API answers. As below.

(1) Initial state: res is an empty array.
(2) 1st render: res is undefined. Exception throws if the 2nd log is not commented.
...some times pass, the time for the API to answer...
(3) 2nd render because a state changed: now res[0] is defined

So I think your exception happens on 1st render, and thus 2nd render is never reached. Try adding a "if (res.length > 0)" around the log.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `componentWillMount()` it was depricated in 2018. Update this call to `componentDidMount()`.  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-understand-a-components-lifecycle-methods-in-reactjs-e1a609840630/

Comment: @ricola3D You're right, there are two logs for this.state.res[0].name. Both of them say that this.state.res[0] is undefined, even with the if (this.state.res.length > 0) around the log, though.